# Stop code execution when tab or page is closed asp.net?

Tags: c#, linq, crystal-reports-2010

I have been publishing crystal Report and this is one of the most frequent error I get, if I close the tab which shows the report, my code keeps on running till the time report query (LINQ) runs in DAL.
Then my whole application freezes, is there a way by which I can stop the query of the closed tab report?

I just need a hint to do the same.
Thanks in advance, I was not able to search the solution on net as I was doubtful so as what should I ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking for something unusual, so there is no usual way of doing it..

What I would try is to use jQuery and the unload event of the document to send a small REST request (if it's asp.net, then add an HTTP Handler -http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001).

Add an identifier to the query string of the request and then at your server you can make sure the request was from the IP that matches the identifier of the client by checking Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].

Then you're at your server, with an identifier and you made sure it's the client who sent it by unloading the page (closing the tab/browser).
As I'm not farmiliar with crystal resports, you should search for how it's possible to stop it: https://www.google.co.il/search?num=30&biw=1280&bih=699&q=stop+or+abort+a+crystal+report+asp.net&oq=stop+or+abort+a+crystal+report+asp.net